# Change mesh following pose

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I would like to know how I can change a mesh and keep bone deformations while in edit mode, because currently, my mesh (which is a hair) is following the deformation of the pose, but I would like to change an error that happens with the deformation, but when I enter edit mode, it returns to the initial state.

Is it possible to keep the warp in edit mode?

Thanks!!

Comment: In the Armature modifier, enable the 2 first options (not sure what you mean when you that it's hair though)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks!  That was it!

Answer (score 0):

In the *Armature* modifier, enable the 2 first options (*On Cage* and *Edit Mode*) and once in *Edit* mode you'll see the mesh as transformed by the armature:

[image]